# Ajax with JQuery: 200 ok, but “failed”

Tags: ajax

i have javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Game_Php/check_answer.php",
            data:{ans:$('#name').val()},
            dataType : "string",
            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

                alert("success");

            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
     $ans =$_GET['ans'];
    if( $ans == $_SESSION['answer'] )
    {
        echo "correct";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "incorrect";
    }

die();
?>
```

but dosent work and fail ajax request,this code sent my data and compare but the request is error,i dont know why dosent work,
help please

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code. Check the console in your browser and tell us the error(s). The page you're requesting may not exist.

Comment: thanks for your comment, ajax failed and in my console:  Object { readyState=4, responseText="incurrect", status=200, more...}

Comment: status=200 means that the response was successful. Your ajax is not failing if that's the response you are getting.

Comment: i know ,but in firefox alert failed